# Read the Realm property in HTTP authentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication, webresponse

How can I read the Realm property sent in the WWW-Authenticate header by a server requesting HTTP Basic authentication?

Comment: Reiterating the title doesn't really help. Can you please go into a bit more detail?

Comment: it's clear enough . i get the help i want . thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue the down-voters have with this question really is.

Here's the rough code to get the WWW-Authenticate header that contains the Basic authentication realm. Extracting the actual realm value from the header is left as an exercise, but should be quite straightforward (e.g. using regular expression).

```
public static string GetRealm(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        using (request.GetResponse())
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Response == null) return null;
        var auth = e.Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.WwwAuthenticate];
        if (auth == null) return null;
        // Example auth value:
        // Basic realm="Some realm"
        return ...Extract the value of "realm" here (with a regex perhaps)...
    }
}
```

Comment: that's really help. 
thanks a lot

Comment: Yes.  This is exactly what I needed.  I use this to help determine whether or not I'm about to connect to a web service that is hosted in a Kerberos website.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to create a Web Request with Basic Authentication.

If that's the correct assumption, the following code is what you need:

```
// Create a request to a URL
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
string usernamePassword = "username:password";
//Use the CredentialCache so we can attach the authentication to the request
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
myReq.Credentials = mycache;
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));
//Send and receive the response
WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```